# Don't override "nobody" user/group when uploading files to the directory

Tags: permissions, ftp

I have a website directory that has files with both user and group "nobody". Hovewer when I upload new files or override old ones they have user and group "root". Is there some command that would permanently set default group and user for that directory and all its children to be "nobody:nobody"?

Answer (score 0):

**You must not use `root` login for anything that doesn't need the privileges of `root` user.** If remote `root` login is allowed, that is a security issue too.

File uploading is one such thing. You need to log in as a user that has write privileges to the folder.

In your case the following permission scheme could work:

- your upload user would belong to `nobody` group
- `nobody` group has read/write privileges on the folder
- optionally, `setgid` flag would be set on the directory, so that the group is inherited by files and subdirectories